# Add data in Firestore with Clojure

Tags: clojure, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to the Firestore and Clojure.
Below is my code, Get returns the correct data, however, Set is not successful, without any exception or response.

```
(defn database-instance
  []
  (FirestoreClient/getFirestore))

(def user (java.util.HashMap. {"age" 50
                           "name" "Josh"
                           "user_id" "user02"}))

(defn get-credit-detail!
  [msg]
  (def result
    (-> (database-instance)
      (.collection "credits")
      (.document "document")
      (.get)
      (.get)
      ))
  (println (.getData result))

;; this Set does not work
  (-> (database-instance)
    (.collection "credits")
    (.document "document1")
    (.set user)
    )
  )
```

Can you help me with the Set to be able to add new data to firestore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A little late to answer this but what you have should work.  I tried it through the REPL and verified the set worked from the firebase console. Note that you can use a Clojure map with String keys as input without having to resort to creating a `java.util.Map`.

```
(-> (database-instance)
    (.collection "credits")
    (.document "document1")
    (.set {"age" 50 "name" "Josh" "user_id" "user02"}))
```